# Conditional Formatting, although applied no format comes up

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

First off this is one of the best forums ive been on. I've only recently created an account but I have already learned so much from this forum.

My question as per the title is with regards to Conditional Formatting. As seen below in the code I have so far I have applied a background color as the formatting. But after running this macro, although the conditions are applied to the selected cells there is no formatting to with it. When I click on manage existing rules, the conditions are there but it comes up with "No Format Set". As can be seen here: [image: Screenshot]

```
Sub tableSetup()

    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=Selection, xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlYes, tablestylename:="Custom")

    cellStr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Address
    cellStr = Replace(cellStr, "$", "")
    formulaStr = "=IsFormula(" & cellStr & ")"

    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formulaStr
        .FormatConditions.Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: My preferred way of proceeding in this case : record a macro while manually (through the GUI) setting conditionnal formating on a set of cells. Then look at the generated code it will probably show you the missing bit.

Comment: fwiw, `cellStr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)` produces a relative row/relative column cell address you don't have to replace the $ out of.

Comment: I will attempt recording a macro now/

Comment: Thank you Jeeped that is very useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't telling it which FormatConditions to apply the formatting to.

```
With tbl.DataBodyRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formulaStr
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
End With
```

You've deleted all other .FormatConditions so legitimately, this could be referred to as .FormatConditions(1) but when you add a .FormatConditions, it is always the last one in the queue until you do something like .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority which moves it to the front of the queue.

You can also use the object created with .FormatConditions.Add to form a nested With ... End With block for correctly referencing multiple operations.

```
With tbl.DataBodyRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formulaStr)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .SetFirstPriority
    end with
End With
```

Comment: It is possible that I am doing something wrong, but running the macro with the code amended to your suggestion above results in the same situation. Any further thoughts?

Comment: The above answer did not seem to work for the original workbook for some reason. However it does work when placed into another workbook. I am not sure why this is but you have answered the question posted. Thanks a million!

Comment: I have one more question related to this thread. Is there any reason as to why this is not working as part of an addin?

Comment: As an XLA or COM add-in? No, I cannot think of anything off the top of my head.

Comment: XLA, It produces an error in the line where the formatcondition is being added.

Invalid procedure or call